# edit a specific line in text file using batch command

Tags: batch-file

I have a textfile which contains the following text.

"Module"

> ```
>  {
>     "ModuleSignature" = "8:MergeModule.6F1248514B3047E99E4EE8A129CB8605"
>     "Version" = "8:1.0.0.0"
>     "Title" = "8:uoipmsm"
>     "Subject" = "8:"
>     "Author" = "8:Microsoft"
>     "Keywords" = "8:"
>     "Comments" = "8:"
>     "SearchPath" = "8:"
>     "UseSystemSearchPath" = "11:TRUE"
>     "TargetPlatform" = "3:1"
>     "PreBuildEvent" = "8:"
>     "PostBuildEvent" = "8:"
>     "RunPostBuildEvent" = "3:0"
>     }
> ```

In the above; I want to change the Version number which I will give when I trigger a build from a tool.

I wanna pass a parameter **$Version** in batch file, it has to take the version number from the tool I use and update the same in that text file.

For ex: in the above text i wanna code it as "Version" = "8:$Version" hence when ever I provide a version number while triggering a build, it has to update the same in this text file.

Could you please guide me how to edit the specific line. I am new to windows batch scripting.

and i hav to add one more point... in the text file i have to modify the version in the line number 399. So the batch file has to jump to line num 399 in that text file and modify the same. Kindly help me to fix the same ...

---

I had saved the above script in a text pad and saved the same as ver.bat; and also in the same folder I saved the Intext file. When I mention the line number which to be replaced, it is removing the contents which are present after "=" symbol, from line 1 to 399 .

Before running the batch file:

```
"ModuleSignature" = "8:MergeModule.6F1248514B3047E99E4EE8A129CB8605"
"Version" = "8:1.0.0.0"
"Title" = "8:uoipmsm"
"Subject" = "8:"
"Author" = "8:Microsoft"
"Keywords" = "8:"
"Comments" = "8:"
"SearchPath" = "8:"
"UseSystemSearchPath" = "11:TRUE"
"TargetPlatform" = "3:1"
"PreBuildEvent" = "8:"
"PostBuildEvent" = "8:"
"RunPostBuildEvent" = "3:0"
```

I mentioned the line number as 10 and after tat if I run the batch file; i get the following output;

```
"ModuleSignature" = 
"Version" = ""
"Title" = 
"Subject" = 
"Author" = 
"Keywords" = 
"Comments" = 
"SearchPath" = 
"UseSystemSearchPath" = 
"TargetPlatform" = 
"PreBuildEvent" = 
"PostBuildEvent" = 
"RunPostBuildEvent" =
```

Any idea??

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.  Of course this will have to change if your input file ever changes.  You may also have to make an adjustment if there are blank lines in your input file (they don't count).  Note that you only need to pass the version (not the entire new line 399).  In your example that would be "8:1.0.0.0".  Best to quote the string in case there are ever spaces in there.
By way of explanation, this will:

1. This bat file must be called with an argument
2. Use a FOR LOOP to echo the first 398 lines to a temp file
3. Add a new line 399 using the version passed as an argument
4. Use MORE to append the remaining lines to the temp file
5. Copy the temp file to the original file
6. Delete the temp file

x

```
@echo off
REM %1=Version (use quotes if there are spaces in version)

set ReplaceLine=399
set InFile=Test.txt
set TempFile=TempTest.txt
if exist "%TempFile%" del "%TempFile%"

if "%~1"=="" (
   color CF
   echo.This program must be called with an argument!
   pause
   goto :eof
   )

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /A Cnt=1
for /F "tokens" %%a in (%InFile%) do (
   echo.%%a>> "%TempFile%"
   set /A Cnt+=1
   if !Cnt! GEQ %ReplaceLine% GOTO :ExitLoop
   )
:ExitLoop
endlocal

echo."Version" = "%~1">> "%TempFile%"
more +%ReplaceLine% < "%InFile%">> "%TempFile%"
copy /y "%TempFile%" "%InFile%"
del "%TempFile%"
goto :eof
```