# How do I only change one specific line in a foriegn batch file, without affecting any other line?

Tags: batch-file

I have been playing around with batch script a lot lately, and I am wondering if there is a way of only editing one line of a separate batch file. I recently have been working on a program that will allow me to view, edit, and exchange data in between multiple batch files for a game with me and my friends. What I have below is what I came up with, but I realized that when I would choose, let's say 5, as my line number, it would keep the lines 1-4 in dirid01.bat the same (which I want), line 5 would change to exactly what I want, and the following lines would all delete, so I would only have 1-5 operational, where 6-infinity are now non-existent.

```
title Directory Edit
echo.
echo To edit, enter the number of the desired line, then enter it's new value.
echo.
call dirid01.bat
echo.
echo 1  %n% (ID: 01)
echo 2  !     Leader: %leader%
echo 3  !     !     Gamertag: %lgt%
echo 4  !     !     Networth: %lnw%
echo 5  !     Population: %pop%
echo 6  !     !     Real: %rpop%
echo 7  !     !     NPC: %npcpop%
echo 8  !     !     Wolven: %wolfpop%
echo 9 !     Bank Balance: %bankbal%
echo 10 !     !     Treasurer: %btr%
echo 11 !     !     !     Gamertag: %btrgt%
echo 12 !     !     !     Networth: %btrnw%
echo 13 !     !     Location: %bankloc%
echo 14 !     Allies:
echo 15 !     Enemies:
echo.
set /p num=" >  "
if %num%==exit goto start
if %num%==escape goto start
if %num%==esc goto start
set /p edit=" New value for %num%:  "
if %num%==1 echo set n=%edit% > dirid01.bat
if %num%==2 echo set leader=%edit% >> dirid01.bat
if %num%==3 echo set lgt=%edit% >>> dirid01.bat
if %num%==4 echo set lnw=%edit% >>>> dirid01.bat
if %num%==5 echo set pop=%edit% >>>>> dirid01.bat
if %num%==6 echo set rpop=%edit% >>>>>> dirid01.bat
if %num%==7 echo set npcpop=%edit% >>>>>>> dirid01.bat
if %num%==8 echo set wolfpop=%edit% >>>>>>>> dirid01.bat
if %num%==9 echo set bankbal=%edit% >>>>>>>>> dirid01.bat
if %num%==10 echo set btr=%edit% >>>>>>>>>> dirid01.bat
if %num%==11 echo set btrgt=%edit% >>>>>>>>>>> dirid01.bat
if %num%==12 echo set btrnw=%edit% >>>>>>>>>>>> dirid01.bat
if %num%==13 echo set bankloc=%edit% >>>>>>>>>>>>> dirid01.bat
if %num%==14 echo set n=%edit% >>>>>>>>>>>>>> dirid01.bat
if %num%==15 echo set n=%edit% >>>>>>>>>>>>>>> dirid01.bat
```

So in further detail, before running this script, my sirid01.bat file would be:

```
set n=Artijiet-Union
set leader=Aidan
set lgt=(gamertag)
set lnw=20money
set pop=4000
set rpop=6
set npcpop=3994
set wolfpop=0
set bankbal=1000k
```

So on and so forth. 
After I run the script, changing line 3 to Troller27:

```
set n=Artijiet-Union
set leader=Aidan
set lgt=Troller27
```

So all of the rest of the info got erased. What am I dong wrong?

P.S. Thanks for taking the time to read all of this :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [edit a specific line in text file using batch command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067964/edit-a-specific-line-in-text-file-using-batch-command)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what all those redirectors will do.

`>` means "create a new file or replace any existing file"
`>>` means "append to any existing file or create a new file if it doesn't exist

In your case, #14 and #15 make no sense, and

```
(
if %num%==1 echo set n=%edit%
if %num%==2 echo set leader=%edit%
if %num%==3 echo set lgt=%edit%
...
)>> dirid01.bat
```

will append a new line to the file - any `echo` in the code block (parenthesised series of lines) will be redirected.

Hence, if your original target batch file was

```
set n=Artijiet-Union
set leader=Aidan
set lgt=(gamertag)
...
```

then "altering" line 3 would set the file to

```
set n=Artijiet-Union
set leader=Aidan
set lgt=(gamertag)
...
set lgt=Troller27
```

so `call`ing that batch file would first set `lgt` to `(gamertag)` and then to `Troller27` with the last-set value being "returned".

**Caution** - with the `(echoes)>>filename` syntax, any `)` within the data terminates the block so it won't work for values that may contain `)` - use your original scheme, but `>>`, not `>` or many-`>`

**Alternative scheme for saving games**

If you reserve a character like `#` or `@` or `$` or `_` for all of the variablenames that you want to save in your game, then

```
set #>savefile
```

will save all of your `#` variables in the file in the format

```
#1=value of #1
#3=value of #3
```

and

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (savefile) do set "%%a"
```

will restore all of those saved values.

This makes light work of adding or deleting values-to-be-saved.